# How many independent sets of size 4 has the Petersen graph?

Tags: graph-theory

How many independent sets of size 4 has the Petersen graph? 
 
(You can interpret this as Count to how many independent sets of size 4 belongs a given vertex in the Petersen graph.)

 I recently come across this problem. To be honest I'm not so sure what does independent sets of size 4 mean this context. There are some answers online saying the answer to this question is 5. I would make a wild guess that it is due to the fact that we can make combinations of a set like {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5}} in 5 ways. Effectively simplify this problem to a `(5,4)` combination problem, which gives us 5 as the answer. Would somebody please clarify this for me? Does Petersen graph always have 5 elements in the set? Thanks！

Comment: An [independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) in a graph is a set of vertices, no two of which are adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Petersen graph.

[image]

An independent set of size $4$ containing vertex $1$ must have either vertex $3$ or $4$ (otherwise it would need three of vertices $7, 8, 9, 10$, but that's clearly impossible).
Suppose it contains vertex $3$.  There are three remaining vertices ($8$, $9$ and $10$) not adjacent to $1$ or $3$, of which we need two that are not adjacent: the only possibility is $8$ and $10$.  So the only independent set of size $4$ containing $1$ and $3$ is $\{1,3,8,10\}$.  Similarly, the only independent set of size $4$ containing $1$ and $4$ is $\{1,4,7,9\}$.  Thus there are two independent sets of size $4$ containing vertex $1$.

Similarly, for each of the $5$ outer vertices there are two independent sets of size $4$ 
containing that vertex.  That makes a total of $5$ independent sets of size $4$.